# How can I duplicate the first and last elements of a vector?

Tags: string, vector, rust

I would like to take a vector of characters and duplicate the first letter and the last one.

The only way I managed to do that is with this ugly code:

```rust
fn repeat_ends(s: &Vec<char>) -> Vec<char> {
    let mut result: Vec<char> = Vec::new();
    let first = s.first().unwrap();
    let last = s.last().unwrap();

    result.push(*first);
    result.append(&mut s.clone());
    result.push(*last);

    result
}

fn main() {
    let test: Vec<char> = String::from("Hello world !").chars().collect();

    println!("{:?}", repeat_ends(&test)); // "HHello world !!"
}
```

What would be a better way to do it?

Comment: With [`insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.insert) for the first character and [`push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push) for the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if it is "better" but one way is using slice patterns:

```rust
fn repeat_ends(s: &Vec<char>) -> Vec<char> {
    match s[..] {
        [first, .. , last ] => {
            let mut out = Vec::with_capacity(s.len() + 2);
            out.push(first);
            out.extend(s);
            out.push(last);
            out
        },
        _ => panic!("whatever"), // or s.clone()
    }
}
```

If it can be mutable:

```rust
fn repeat_ends(s: &mut Vec<char>) {
    if let [first, .. , last ] = s[..] {
        s.insert(0, first);
        s.push(last);
    }
}
```

Comment: Really cool technic!  But is there a way to make it simpler if my vector is mutable ?

Comment: The pattern matching trick to extract the first and last characters is pretty cool, but it will fail if there is only one character in the input. Eg. I would expect `repeat_ends (['a'])` to return `['a', 'a', 'a']` but your solution will either panic or return `['a']`

Answer (score 2):

If it's ok to mutate the original vector, this does the job:

```rust
fn repeat_ends(s: &mut Vec<char>) {
    let first = *s.first().unwrap();
    s.insert(0, first);

    let last = *s.last().unwrap();
    s.push(last);
}

fn main() {
    let mut test: Vec<char> = String::from("Hello world !").chars().collect();
    repeat_ends(&mut test);
    println!("{}", test.into_iter().collect::<String>()); // "HHello world !!"
}
```

---

[`Vec::insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.insert):

> Inserts an element at position index within the vector, shifting all elements after it to the right.

This means the function `repeat_ends` would be `O(n)` with n being the number of characters in the vector. I'm not sure if there is a more efficient method if you need to use a vector, but I'd be curious to hear it if there is.